# Add Text Color to a CKEditor in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, yarnpkg

CKEditor is a great editor.  My app has been using it perfectly for several weeks, and now I need to add a button so that the user can color some text.

Previously, I used Yarn to add *'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'* and *'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'* to my packages.  Today I added *'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font'* .

imports:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { Font, fontColor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';
```

Component

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    data={editorValue}
    config={{
        toolbar: [
            'heading',
            'bold',
             (About six other buttons)
             'fontColor',
                  
          ],
     }}
      onChange={onChangeFunction}
 />
```

I've also tried using the phrase "color", "colorButton", and "textColor" in the toolbar options.  Along with all the possible capital letter combinations.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Font is the default export on that module, so no curly braces are used:`import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font'`